# How to have PostSharp included in build process for ASP.NET WebApi project when installed using our own Nuget package?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, nuget, postsharp

We have a class library (C#, .NET 5) where we've added a reference to the PostSharp nuget-package (using `PackageReference` in our csproj-file) and implemented a PostSharp `OnMethodBoundaryAspect`. This class library is then packaged into a Nuget package to be consumed by our micro services/WebApi-projects.

When I add a reference to this nuget-package in one of our ASP.NET WebApi project I see that references to PostSharp and PostSharp.Redist are also being included along with our class library.

However, when adding the `OnMethodBoundaryAspect` to one of our functions in the WebApi-project the code in the aspect is not being executed. If I add a reference to PostSharp directly in the WebApi-project it works just fine.

How do I make sure that PostSharp is being included in the build process in our WebApi-project when it is being included from our own Nuget-package?

This answer to another question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/68470518/182380) on StackOverflow mentions that `PostSharp.targets` needs to be included in the build process and installing the PostSharp nuget-package will make this happen, but what if I want to include PostSharp from our own Nuget-package and have it included in the build process of the WebApi-project that way, how do I go about fixing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a result of NuGet's behavior of project references (build-time parts of the package are not taken from referenced projects).

For your own package, it should be enough to have a dependency (in the .nuspec file or appropriately configured csproj) on `PostSharp` package, which would then include all `PostSharp` package assets in the project where you've referenced your package (this is the default behavior of NuGet dependency if you don't specify any `includeAssets` and `excludeAssets`).

In case of `PackageReference` in your project file, you also need to set `privateAssets` to `none`, because the default behavior is `Build,Analyzers`:

```
<PackageReference Include="PostSharp" Version="6.9.9" PrivateAssets="none" />
```

Comment: In our Nuget-package we have a reference to Postsharp in the csproj-file looking like this:
`<PackageReference Include="PostSharp" Version="6.9.9" />`
If I understand you correctly this should be enough? We have no nuspec-file in this class library, we just call "dotnet pack" referencing this csproj-file. Still have to also add a reference to PostSharp in the project that references our own Nuget-package.

Comment: I forgot to mention that for PackageReferences which are used by `dotnet pack` you also need to specify `PrivateAssets` as `none` as the default is `Build,Analyzers`. This will result in correct `.nuspec` file being generated. This means the reference should be: `<PackageReference Include="PostSharp" Version="6.9.9" PrivateAssets="none" />`